# paho mqtt javascript client cannot subscribe to a topic

Tags: ionic2, mqtt, paho

> AMQJS0005E Internal error. Error Message: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

I included eclipse paho javascript client library in my app.
connection is established but, I cannot subscribe to a topic.
here is the code that I used..

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams ,MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Setuser } from '../../providers/setuser';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Paho} from 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31';
/*
  Generated class for the Usershome page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-usershome',
  templateUrl: 'usershome.html'
})
export class UsershomePage {
  client :any;
  message :any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public menu:MenuController,public setUserProvider: Setuser,public platform:Platform) {
   this.menu.open(); 
    
  }
  

  ionViewDidLoad() {
   this.menu.enable(true);
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad UsershomePage');
  }
  exitApp(){
  console.log("----------");
  this.platform.exitApp();
  }
  connectToMqtt(){
  this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("test.mosquitto.org",8080,"abc");

// set callback handlers
this.client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
this.client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived;

// connect the client
this.client.connect({onSuccess:this.onConnect});
}

// called when the client connects
 onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("onConnect");
  this.client.subscribe("mitsuruog");
  this.message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
  this.message.destinationName = "World";
  this.client.send(this.message);
}

// called when the client loses its connection
 onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
  if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
    console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
  }
}

// called when a message arrives
 onMessageArrived(message) {
  console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
}
  
  

 

}
```

Comment: This is a scope problem, `this` does not point to what you think it does when in the `onConnect` callback

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is solvable by modifying the line

```
this.client.connect({onSuccess:this.onConnect.bind(this)});
```

or, surprisingly for you, by **removing all `this.` in front of `client` and `message` references**.

You should learn what exactly means `this` in JavaScript. Not the same thing as in Java or C#. To understand why the removal works, learn about closures and arrow functions.

Good starting point (your question could be actually flagged as duplicate of this one):
[How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)